# Returning a Tuple List from an action and rendering it in the View model ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, list, tuples

I have been going crazy over this one, I create a function that returns a tuple List, next is to store that List in another List which I want to render in the View.

The tuple List is of different type Lists.

Controller:

```
 public List<Tuple<List<string>, List<TimeSpan>, List<TimeSpan>, List<int>, List<int>, List<TimeSpan>, List<TimeSpan>>> completeStats(int EnrollNumber, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate)
        {

//some code

  List<Tuple<List<string>, List<TimeSpan>, List<TimeSpan>, List<int>, List<int>, List<TimeSpan>, List<TimeSpan>>> generalList = new List<Tuple<List<string>, List<TimeSpan>, List<TimeSpan>, List<int>, List<int>, List<TimeSpan>, List<TimeSpan>>>();

//some more code

   List<string> Name = new List<string>();
            List<TimeSpan> ArrivalTime = new List<TimeSpan>();
            List<int> FineList = new List<int>();
            List<TimeSpan> ArrList = new List<TimeSpan>();
            List<int> MinList = new List<int>();
            List<TimeSpan> DepartList = new List<TimeSpan>();
            List<TimeSpan> TimeSpentList = new List<TimeSpan>();


            for (int i = 0; i < fineList.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (fineList[i] > 0)
                {
                    Name.Add(empObj2.FirstName);
                    ArrivalTime.Add(AT);
                    FineList.Add(fineList[i]);
                    ArrList.Add(ArrivalList[i]);
                    MinList.Add(minutesList[i]);
                    DepartList.Add(departList[i]);
                    TimeSpentList.Add(timeSpentList[i]);
                }
            }

 generalList.Add(new Tuple<List<string>, List<TimeSpan>, List<TimeSpan>, List<int>, List<int>, List<TimeSpan>, List<TimeSpan>>(
               Name, ArrList , ArrivalTime, MinList, FineList, DepartList, TimeSpentList

                ));
            return generalList;
}
```

now in th Index Action:

```
 public ActionResult Index(int? EnrollNumber, DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EndDate)
        {

//some code

  var generalList2 = new List<Tuple<List<string>, List<TimeSpan>, List<TimeSpan>, List<int>, List<int>, List<TimeSpan>, List<TimeSpan>>>();


//the line below does not work, why?
  //generalList2.Add(completeStats(Convert.ToInt32(emp.EnrollNumber), startDate, endDate));

//the line below works but this does not add all the list but only the last one
  //generalList2 = completeStats(Convert.ToInt32(emp.EnrollNumber), startDate, endDate);

//this works but obviously is not a good approach and slows down ALOT

 generalList2.Add(new Tuple<List<string>, List<TimeSpan>, List<TimeSpan>, List<int>, List<int>, List<TimeSpan>, List<TimeSpan>>( 
                            completeStats(Convert.ToInt32(emp.EnrollNumber), startDate, endDate).FirstOrDefault().Item1,
                            completeStats(Convert.ToInt32(emp.EnrollNumber), startDate, endDate).FirstOrDefault().Item2,
                            completeStats(Convert.ToInt32(emp.EnrollNumber), startDate, endDate).FirstOrDefault().Item3,
                            completeStats(Convert.ToInt32(emp.EnrollNumber), startDate, endDate).FirstOrDefault().Item4,
                            completeStats(Convert.ToInt32(emp.EnrollNumber), startDate, endDate).FirstOrDefault().Item5,
                            completeStats(Convert.ToInt32(emp.EnrollNumber), startDate, endDate).FirstOrDefault().Item6,
                            completeStats(Convert.ToInt32(emp.EnrollNumber), startDate, endDate).FirstOrDefault().Item7
                         ));

//next is to render the lists in the View, I tried with ViewBag instead.
 ViewBag.generalList = generalList2;
                return View(generalList2);
```

View:

```
<table @*class="table table-striped table-responsive"*@ id="myTable" class="tablesorter" cellspacing="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
               Name
            </th>
            <th>
               Scheduled Arrival Time
            </th>
            <th>
                Arrival Time
            </th>
                Late Mins
            <th>
                Fine Imposed
            </th>
            <th>
               Scheduled Departure Time
            </th>
            <th>
               Departure Time
            </th>
            <th>
               TimeSpent
            </th>
            <th>
               DateTime
            </th>
            <th>
                Action
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.generalList)
        {
            foreach (var item2 in item.Item1)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item2
                    </td>

                    @foreach (var item3 in item.Item2)
                    {

                    <td>
                        @item3
                    </td>
                    }

                    @foreach (var item4 in item.Item3)
                    {

                        <td>
                            @item4

                        </td>
                    }


                    @foreach (var item5 in item.Item4)
                    {

                        <td>
                            @item5
                        </td>
                    }

                    @foreach (var item6 in item.Item5)
                    {

                        <td>
                            @item6

                        </td>
                    }

                    @foreach (var item7 in item.Item6)
                    {

                        <td>
                            @item7

                        </td>
                    }

                    @foreach (var item8 in item.Item7)
                    {

                        <td>
                            @item8
                        </td>
                    }

                     @*<td>
                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-circle btn-group-sm btn-group solid">
                            @*<button type="button" class="btn blue" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "FineReport", new { id = item.CronID })'" style="">Edit &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>*@
                    @*<button type="button" class="btn green" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Details", "FineReport", new { id = item.CronID })'" style="">View &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>*@
                    @*<button type="button" class="btn red" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Delete", "FineReport", new { id = item.CronID })'" style="">Delete &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
                            </div>
                        </td>*@

                </tr>
            }

        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now the snippet in the view above is very messed up as it does not renders the lists as expected. I tried with different `<tr>` approaches getting all messy records (mostly redundant entries). The list `generalList2` has 7 different Lists with each list having different number of elements (Items in this case).

UPDATED: Continuing from Peter's suggestion I adopted the Viewmodel approach like below;

```
public class Agenda
{

    public IList<string> Names { get; set; }
    public IList<TimeSpan> ArrivalTimes { get; set; }
    public IList<int> Fines { get; set; }
    public IList<TimeSpan> ArrList { get; set; }
    public IList<int> MinList { get; set; }
    public IList<TimeSpan> Departures { get; set; }
    public IList<TimeSpan> TimesSpent { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? EnrollNumber, DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EndDate)
        {
 var empId = db.Employees.Where(x => x.EnrollNumber == EnrollNumber.ToString()).Select(x => x.EmployeeId);

                var getLoggedID = SessionManager.CurrentUser.EmployeeId;
                var dept = db.Departments.Where(x => x.LeadBy == SessionManager.CurrentUser.EmployeeId).FirstOrDefault();

                var teams = db.Teams.Where(x => x.DeptID == dept.DepartmentId);

                List<Employee> refinedEmpList = new List<Employee>();
                var empList = db.Employees.ToList();
                foreach (var v in teams)
                {
                    foreach (var c in empList)
                    {
                        if (v.TeamID == c.TeamId)
                        {
                            refinedEmpList.Add(c);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (EnrollNumber != null && StartDate != null && EndDate != null)
                {
                    foreach (var emp in refinedEmpList)
                    {
 agenda.Add(completeStats(Convert.ToInt32(emp.EnrollNumber), StartDate.Value, EndDate.Value));


                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var emp in refinedEmpList)
                    {
                        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                        var startDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
                        var endDate = now.Date;
   agenda.Add(completeStats(Convert.ToInt32(emp.EnrollNumber), startDate, endDate));



                    }
                }
 return View(agenda);
```

View:

```
<h2>Late Fine Report</h2>
@{
    int sum = 0;
 }

<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
 <th>
                Total Fine
            </th>
            <th>
                Action
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        @foreach (var agenda in Model)
        {
            if (agenda.Fines.Contains(0))
            {
                continue;
            }

            sum += agenda.Fines.Sum();
                <tr>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => agenda.Names)
                    </td>
 <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => agenda.Fines)
                    </td>
 <td>


                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-circle btn-group-sm btn-group solid">

    </div>
                                    </td>
                 </tr>

            }
        <tr>
            <td>
               <b> Total </b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b> @sum</b>
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>

 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myTable").tablesorter();
        }
    );
    </script>
<script>
        $(function () {

            var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
            var end = moment();

            function cb(start, end) {
                $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
            }

            $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
                startDate: start,
                endDate: end,
                ranges: {
                    'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                    'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                    'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                    'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                    'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                    'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
                }
            }, cb);

            cb(start, end);

        });

    </script>
 <script>
        function onSubmit(){
            var baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")';
            id = $('.selected-item').val();
            if(id == null || id == ""){
                console.log("enroll null");
                id = @Session["currentEmpID"].ToString();
                console.log("after enroll null: " + id);
            }
            console.log("Dropdown enroll: " + id);
            var x = document.getElementById("reportRange").innerText;
            s = $("#startDate").val();
            e = $("#endDate").val();

            var res = x.split("-");


            a = res[0], b = res[1];

            var sDate = new Date(a);
            var eDate = new Date(b);

            s = (sDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + sDate.getDate() + '/' + sDate.getFullYear();
            e = (eDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + eDate.getDate() + '/' + eDate.getFullYear();
            console.log("Fine CompStats SS: " + s);
            console.log("Fine CompStats EE: " + e);



            if (s == null && e == null)
            {
                // Return today's date and time
                var currentTime = new Date()

                // returns the month (from 0 to 11)
                var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1

                // returns the day of the month (from 1 to 31)
                var endingDay = currentTime.getDate()

                // returns the year (four digits)
                var year = currentTime.getFullYear()

                var s1 = new Date(year, month - 1, 1); //Thu Feb 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)

                s1.getMonth() + 1  // 01
                s1.getDate()     // 02
                s1.getFullYear() // 2018

                console.log("starting date: " + s1);

                var s = (s1.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + s1.getDate() + "/" + s1.getFullYear();   //behtreen cheypi
                console.log("starting date: " + s);
                //        var s = '2/01/2018';
                var e = '@DateTime.Today.Date';
            }



            console.log("compStat start: " + s);
            console.log("compStat end: " + e);


            $.ajax({
                url: baseUrl + 'FineReport/Index?EnrollNumber=' + id + '&StartDate=' + moment(s).format("YYYY-MM-DD") + '&EndDate=' + moment(e).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                contenttype: 'application/json',
                data: '',
                type: 'post'
            }).done(function (data) {
                //console.log('KKcurrent time:', data);
                console.log('lateRec ' + data);
            });
            //}, 1000);
        }
    </script>
```

ISSUE:
Apart from being working fine, the problem is that it displays the same data every time, even when I give it the select `startDate` and `endDate` from the `daerangepicker`, funny thing is that when  inspected the Console on the browser it actually shows the data according to the selected date range but not the view, why? Attached pictures below:

Scenario 1: (by default when the index is loaded, no dates are given and so the month report is displayed)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0A8S.png)

Scenario 2: Now when I give a date range of 12 March - 14 March it displays the same result but if you see it in the console it is returning the expected result
     [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikj8E.png)

Comment: downvoter? please explain on how I could improve my question instead.

Comment: I know this is not codereview, but may I suggest you should start by changing the use of Tuple to using custom classes that are more descriptive? When you look at the view you have no clue what item1/2/3/... actually means. This at least makes your code more readable and makes it easier for us to identify your problem.

Comment: @Peter I know the sequence of Items, Item1 is the string list, Item2 being TimeSpan list, Item3 is also TimeSpan list and so on.. as its declared at  `var generalList2 = new List<Tuple<List<string>, List<TimeSpan>, List<TimeSpan>, List<int>, List<int>, List<TimeSpan>, List<TimeSpan>>>();`

Comment: Yes, you know because you've just written the code. But if you'd look at this code a year from now, you won't anymore. You'd have to go to the controller to see what's what. Not trying to judge, only here to help. What I'm thinking is that if you first refactor your code by getting rid of the Tuple, you will probably solve your own problem as I feel it's clouding the issue at the moment.

Comment: @Peter I appreciate that, but I don't see any other way to pass those multiple lists and get them displayed in the View, Shall I add screenshots to clarify the question more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peter has already given a better path, moving to the edited quesion; there are two ways to solve the issue.

The Problem is;

> you are not clearing the model table before applying the latest data
>   which is why it sticks to the old one

on your `OnSubmit();`

```
<script>
        function onSubmit(){
            var baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")';
            id = $('.selected-item').val();
            if(id == null || id == ""){
                console.log("enroll null");
                id = @Session["currentEmpID"].ToString();
                console.log("after enroll null: " + id);
            }
            console.log("Dropdown enroll: " + id);
            var x = document.getElementById("reportRange").innerText;
            s = $("#startDate").val();
            e = $("#endDate").val();

            var res = x.split("-");


            a = res[0], b = res[1];

            var sDate = new Date(a);
            var eDate = new Date(b);

            s = (sDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + sDate.getDate() + '/' + sDate.getFullYear();
            e = (eDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + eDate.getDate() + '/' + eDate.getFullYear();
            console.log("Fine CompStats SS: " + s);
            console.log("Fine CompStats EE: " + e);



            if (s == null && e == null)
            {
                // Return today's date and time
                var currentTime = new Date()

                // returns the month (from 0 to 11)
                var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1

                // returns the day of the month (from 1 to 31)
                var endingDay = currentTime.getDate()

                // returns the year (four digits)
                var year = currentTime.getFullYear()

                var s1 = new Date(year, month - 1, 1); //Thu Feb 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)

                s1.getMonth() + 1  // 01
                s1.getDate()     // 02
                s1.getFullYear() // 2018

                console.log("starting date: " + s1);

                var s = (s1.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + s1.getDate() + "/" + s1.getFullYear();   //behtreen cheypi
                console.log("starting date: " + s);
                //        var s = '2/01/2018';
                var e = '@DateTime.Today.Date';
            }



            console.log("compStat start: " + s);
            console.log("compStat end: " + e);


            $.ajax({
                url: baseUrl + 'FineReport/Index?EnrollNumber=' + id + '&StartDate=' + moment(s).format("YYYY-MM-DD") + '&EndDate=' + moment(e).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                contenttype: 'application/json',
                data: '',
                type: 'post'
            }).done(function (data) {
                //console.log('KKcurrent time:', data);
                console.log('lateRec ' + data);
            });
            //}, 1000);
        }
    </script>
```

1) return a json object instead of the model view inside the controller that will give you latest table data.

2) Inside the View above, wrap the table with a `<div>` like;

```
div id="tableContainer">
    <table id="myTable" name="myTable" class="tablesorter">
//
</div>
```

and then in the script make the changes;

```
 $('#myTable').html('');

            $.ajax({
                url: baseUrl + 'FineReport/Index?EnrollNumber=' + id + '&StartDate=' + moment(s).format("YYYY-MM-DD") + '&EndDate=' + moment(e).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                contenttype: 'application/json',
                data: '',
                type: 'post'
            }).done(function (data) {
 var result = $(data).find('#tableContainer');
 $('#tableContainer').html(result);

            });
```

This will find the selected element and append it to the table, notice that I cleared the table right before ajax  with;

```
$('#myTable').html('');
```

Answer (score 0):

First, using Tuple's like this is basically avoiding the creation of a custom class. May I suggest you create a new model in your project : /Models/Agenda.cs
Which would look like this:

```
public class Agenda {
    public IList<string> Names {get;set;}
    public IList<TimeSpan> ArrivalTimes {get;set;}
    public IList<int> Fines {get;set;}
    public IList<TimeSpan> ArrList {get;set;}
    public IList<int> MinList {get;set;}
    public IList<TimeSpan> Departures {get;set;}
    public IList<TimeSpan> TimesSpent {get;set;}
}
```

Now in your view you could specify that the model of the view is a list of this class:

```
@model IList<Agenda>
```

And then you can call your view from the controller as such:

```
return View(myListOfAgendas)
```

without having to use the ViewBag.
Now you can access the model inside the view with the property ´Model´.
As a small example:

```
<table>
@foreach(var agenda in Model){
    <tr>
        ....
    </tr>
}
```

But as I mentioned in the comments. I know this is not an answer to your question, but I think if you refactor the code as such, you'll make it much simpler to understand.

Comment: Aye Aye Pete. Let me adopt this approach.

Comment: Good luck and let me know how it goes!